# Find the basis for kernel of this weird matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The general way to look for kernels is to use the elementary row operations and try to reduce those rows as much as possible. But, now I'm trying to solve a bit less straight-forward problem.

$$\vec x, \vec y, \vec z \in \mathbb{K}^{2013}$$
$$A=[\vec x + \vec y, \vec x - \vec y, \vec x + \vec z, \vec x - \vec z, \vec x +\vec y + \vec z]$$

What's the kernel basis for $A$? I've found the image basis using el. column operations and, unless I've made a mistake, it's simply $\vec y, \vec x, \vec z$. This was easier, since $A$ has 5 columns. Now, what can I do with its 2013 rows to find the kernel?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, just remember that a matrix's rank by columns is just the same that its rank by rows...

Comment: @DonAntonio You mean the fact that $\dim (\mathrm{span} (\vec c_1 .. \vec c_5)) = \dim (\mathrm{span} (\vec r_1 .. \vec r_{2013})$ ? Sorry, but I still don't see how that helps. I'm terrible at this :/

Comment: Yes, I meant that...and since you said you already calculated the image basis then you already know what its dimension is, don't you?!

Comment: @DonAntonio It's 3, isn't it? So I know that the dimension of kernel basis is 3 as well, but does it mean that I can freely work with only first 3 rows? And Instead of $\vec x, \vec y, \vec z$ use their coordinates?

Comment: Oh, I dunno, @Dunno ! I wouldn't mess in general with such a disgusting thing. But assuming you're right, then yes: you just have to choose any three **linearly dependent** rows.

Comment: @DonAntonio Dependent? I thought basis has to be linearly independent? I must be mistaken about what Kernel actually is... oh man, I'm gonna fail this exam (I have it in about 2 hours)

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo: it should say **independent**, of course.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the great idea to worry about stuff a few hours *before* an exam, in particular a mathematics exam and at college-university level.

Comment: @DonAntonio whew, at least I got that one right. Thanks for your help!